Hiding secrets in GitHub Actions workflow logs
I'm currently facing an issue with my GitHub Actions workflow related to handling secrets. I've added several secrets as environment variables in my repository, intending to allow a select group of developers to view and verify these values. However, I'm concerned about the visibility of these secrets in the workflow logs.
Here’s a brief overview of my setup:

Secrets Configuration: I've defined secrets in both GitHub Actions environment variables and repository environment variables to enable specific developers to see and update them as needed. This is all done within a private repository.
Current Behavior: When I reference these secrets in my GitHub Actions workflow, they are being printed in the logs. I understand that this might be GitHub's way of providing feedback on what is being executed, but it poses a potential security risk since it exposes sensitive information.
Goal: I want to keep these secrets hidden in the logs while still allowing access for the designated developers.

Here's a snippet of my workflow configuration for reference:
jobs:
  Setup:
    name: Setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Validate and Apply Secrets
        run: |
          echo '${{ vars.REPO_SECRET }}' > secret.json

Is there a way to prevent these secrets from being printed in the workflow logs?

Depending on what it is, it might get automatically redacted. If not that also says how to mask it yourself.

Making is not working in my case as that's the way GitHub print the command being executed or environment variables being called.

I've no idea what a you're trying to say, please give a [mre].

@jonrsharpe I meant masking is not working, It seems to be GitHub's way to print the command being executed or environment variables being called.
In GitHub Actions, when you execute a command like echo hello, the platform displays both the command and its output in the logs. The command is typically nested under a dropdown, so users often don’t see it unless they choose to expand that section. This behaviour is standard in GitHub Actions.
The same happens with the Environment variable.

You have choosen "repository (environment) variables" instead of "repository (environment) secrets", this is a feature that has been added to allow to opt out of all secret masking by using (non secret) variables.

Remove REPO_SECRET from the repository (environment) variables
Add REPO_SECRET as repository secret, this is a tab away from variables
If you are actually using deployment environment secrets you need the environment: name of your job as well with the correct name or the value is blank
Replace ${{ vars.REPO_SECRET }} by ${{ secrets.REPO_SECRET }}

Finally the job should look like this
jobs:
  Setup:
    name: Setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Validate and Apply Secrets
        run: |
          echo '${{ secrets.REPO_SECRET }}' > secret.json


while still allowing access for the designated developers.


In workflows they would still have access
Everyone sees *** everywhere in the log file
The command would be printed as echo '***' > secrets.json
you can no longer see the values in settings except the name.

Consider to instead map the secret as step env variable like this, because your example breaks and allow code injection via many symbols including '
      - name: Validate and Apply Secrets
        run: |
          echo "$REPO_SECRET" > secret.json
        env:
          REPO_SECRET: ${{ secrets.REPO_SECRET }}

It's impossible to mask anything coming from any expression context via ::add-mask:: like you noticed yourself
